# Domain chages by simplifying expression

Tags: real-analysis

I am a little confused because $$1/(2-\sqrt{x})+1/(2+\sqrt{x})$$ is only defined for $x\ge 0, x\neq 4$.
But this expression is the same as $$4/(4-x)$$ whis is defined for $x\neq4$, $x\ge 0$ is allowed.

How can this be?

Comment: How do you justify the same phenomenon for $\sqrt{x} \times \sqrt{x} = x$?

Comment: if $x$ is not $$x\geq0$$ then both terms are not equivalent

Comment: The two expressions are equal only if $\ne4$  and $x\ge0$. Otherwise they are not equal. Similarly $x/x=1$ only if $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *function* is a rule that assigns values from one set to another.  When a function is defined, we typically need three ingredients:  a domain, a codomain, and some kind of formula, rule, or other means of assigning elements.

In your example, we could define
$$ f: [0,\infty)\setminus\{4\} \qquad\text{by}\qquad f(x) = \frac{1}{2-\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}},$$
and
$$ g: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{4\} \qquad\text{by}\qquad \frac{4}{4-x}. $$
These two functions are different functions.  Yes, when both functions are defined, they have the same value, but $f$ is only defined for nonnegative values other than 4, while $g$ is defined for all values other than 4.

The underlying idea is that when we simplify an expression, we are transforming it from one function to another.  The two functions are equal *when they are both defined*, but the new function is not generally the same as the old function—the domains are likely to differ.

Answer (score 0):

because

$$
(\sqrt{x})^2=\sqrt{x^2}=x
$$

only if $x\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

Students are taught how to simplify expressions but it is usually not emphasized that the steps they take are often implications and not equivalences.

What you did was prove that

$y=\dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt x} + \dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt x} \quad $ implies
$\quad y=\dfrac{4}{4-x}$

Is a TRUE statement. That means that, if $(x,y)$ satisfies the first equation, then it satisfies the second.

By checking the domains, you have proved that the converse

$y=\dfrac{4}{4-x}$ implies
$y=\dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt x} + \dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt x} \quad $
is FALSE.

It's very much like noticing that,

(if $y=-2$, then $y^2=4$) is a TRUE statement
but (if $y^2=4$, then $y=-2$)
is a FALSE statement.